# how to search for a string in multiple TXT files using PHP

Tags: php, fopen, preg-match-all, readfile

i have PHP code that read multiple **TXT files** and allow the user to make a search on a specified string, and after the system read all text files  and based on the user input the system will display the files name that contain  the user request.

the problem is that when i run the code the webpage display :

> Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 64

where the error in my code and how to fix it ?

## code:

```
<?php

//path to directory
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/";
$txts= glob($directory. "*.txt") or DIE("Unable to open $directory");

$myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');

$line = 1; 

if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $search =$_POST['name'];

 while(!feof($myFileLink)) 
 { 
     $myFileContents = fgets($myFileLink);
     if( preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches))
     {

        foreach($matches[1] as $match)
        {
           echo "Found $match on Line $line";
        }

     }

     ++$line;

 }

}

    fclose($myFileLink);

    ?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <body>
     <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <p>enter your string <input type ="text"  id = "idName"  name="name" /></p>
          <p><input type ="Submit" name ="search" value= "Search" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you echo the $txts variable before fopen. what path are you getting?

Comment: @DeepKakkar it display this note:

**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 7
Array**

Comment: The error messages tell you exactly what the problem is. Your $txts is an array and you can't open an array. You need to loop the array and open each array value one by one

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to fix the problem you need something like this:

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/";
$txts= glob($directory. "*.txt") or DIE("Unable to open $directory");

Foreach ($txts as $txt){
   $myFileLink = fopen($txt, 'r');
   // .... And so on..
```

This will open one file at the time and search them.

---

If you want to improve the code a bit my advice is to first open the file with file_get_contents and do the search on the full text.
If there is a match you can try to find the line number.

Something like:

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/";
$txts= glob($directory. "*.txt") or DIE("Unable to open $directory");

Foreach ($txts as $txt){
    $myFileContents = file_get_contents($txt);
   If(preg_match('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches)){
     // Here we know there is a match in the file, if there is no match there is no need to search each line
```

Comment: I tried your answer  but when i tried to search for a string the system give this message :

**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 50
Found انتقادات in these files Array
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 50
Found انتقادات in these files Array**

this string exist in 2 files

Comment: Line 50? The code you supply us with has 49 lines. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: my mistake sorry i will fix it  i will edit my question because i found the solution but still i need to fix a little issue

Comment: it shows line 50 because i have  a comment  lines but i did not display it 
so now i am runing the code as its on this post

Comment: i notice that the system combine all file in one file and continue the counting of line numbers .... how can i separate each file to make the system start counting from the first line in each file

Comment: @Rany You can't do like this. You have completely changed the question. I flagged this question for moderators with the text *Question has changed. Original question is completely gone from the question. I think it should be deleted*

Comment: Reset the counter, seriously. It's not rocket science

Comment: thank you and sorry  for changing the question  but i did not know that it can't be done like this.

and for the reset counter i fix it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend  using  "Finder" Componnent  from symfony

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html

https://github.com/symfony/finder

In finder it should be something like that

```
$finder=new Finder();
$finder->in($directory)->files()->name('*.txt')->contains($search);

// and it's all -  simple  - isn't  it ? 
//to see all result  you do 

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    $contents = $file->getContents();

    // ...
}
```

You can easilly use it  without  whole symfony  (installing via composer) .

I know  that may look a little  complicated  to you, but  trust me - this is a best php solution for searching in files , and it's definitely worth  to learn